# Application.OnHelp not getting called in Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have assigned an event handler to Application.OnHelp, but it is not getting called.  I have read some other threads about similar problems, but many of them are for Delphi 7 or Delphi 2010.

I have tried using D6OnHelpFix, but that simply changes the problems, rather than resolving them.

At the end of TApplication.DoOnHelp (in Forms) the invocation of FOnHelp always fails inside TMultiCaster.DoHelp in AppEvnts.  That is, the DoHelp routine loops but fails to actually call my event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have used `TApplicationEvents` objects in your code. In which case you need to attach your event handler to the `OnHelp` event of a `TApplicationEvents` object rather then the `OnHelp` event of `TApplication`.

The reason for this is that `TApplicationEvents` replaces the events attached to `TApplication` with its own handlers to perform the multi-cast dispatch.

Comment: Turns out there was a unit which used TApplicationEvents, without my realizing it.  Thanks very much!